# Copy a sheet from one workbook and save in a new workbook with the name being a value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy Sheet2 from Workbook1 and paste it in Sheet1 of a new Workbook and save the new Workbook as the value of cell A1 in Sheet2, Workbook 1. I would like this macro to fire when I click a button that I have added.

Here is what I have done so far but it creates two Workbooks
- One with the correct name but not the content of Sheet2, Workbook1
- And another that has the content of Sheet2, Workbook1 but not the correct Workbook name

```
Sub CreateWorkbook()

Dim n As String
n = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("A1").Value & ".xls"
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs n
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the new workbook created by `Workbooks.Add` becomes `ActiveWorkbook` by default.

Working with `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` can get confusing.

I like to set things like Workbooks and worksheets to variables so you know what your dealing with :)

I couldn't get the `Copy` then `PasteSpecial` bit to work (although I didn't try all that hard).

The example below should do what you want. I used `Sheet2!A1` for the file name, wasnt sure what the `AK545` in your code example was for.

```
Sub Example()
Dim Output As Workbook
Dim FileName As String

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value & ".xls"

Output.SaveAs FileName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Output.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Copy Before:=Output.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Output.Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Output.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer gonna try it now. AK454 is the cell that will be used to name the new work book, just forgot to change it in the code example

Comment: Why do you put `Output.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete`?

Comment: The code doesn't copy the values into `Sheet1` it copies the whole sheet into the new workbook (gets called `Sheet2(2)` due to duplicate name) I delete `Sheet1` so can rename the new sheet to `Sheet1`